# Radiobutton in Customized listview-- one time only one should be selected

Tags: android, android-listview, radio-button

I am stuck in a situation where I need to get the ID of checked Radiobutton. I know where the problem is but I can not solve it so Please suggest me on base of my code.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
    ViewHolder holder=null;

    bean=arrayListCountry.get(position);

    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout_listview, null);
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.textCountryName=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.radioCountry=(RadioButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.relativeCustomLayout);
        relativeLayout.addView(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.textView1,holder.textCountryName);


    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

    holder.radioCountry.setTag(position);

    holder.textCountryName.setText(bean.getCountryName());
    holder.radioCountry.setChecked(bean.getIsSelected());

    holder.radioCountry.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int pos=(Integer)buttonView.getTag();

            Country_Bean country_Bean=arrayListCountry.get(pos);


            coubean.setIsSelected(buttonView.isChecked());


            //buttonView.setChecked(bean.getIsSelected());

            Toast.makeText(context, "POs:"+pos+"\ncountry:"+bean.getCountryName()+"\ncountry_check:"+bean.getIsSelected()+"\nbuttonCheck:"+buttonView.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Please tell me how can I get the specific radiobutton. I also want to know why getView normally used and how can we manually call that method. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I have done from my side and posted the full source code on my Android Blog for the reference.

http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-custon-single-choice-lsitview.html

Comment: Thank you Amit for your post but I think it is more important that we should handle these things without so much help. I tried and I completed the task. SO i didn't need your tutorials. In future if I get stuck somewhere, I will look for to use it. Thanks Again Amit. We will keep in touch for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html)? It is a container for many `RadioButton`s. It even has a method called [getCheckedRadioButtonId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#getCheckedRadioButtonId%28%29).

---

Other than that I see you fail to follow typing conventions. I am very strict when it comes to that and I apologize for the code grammar-nazi inside of me.

If bean is a member variable then use mBean.

```
bean=arrayListCountry.get(position);
```

Will be:

```
mBean=arrayListCountry.get(position);
```

Country_Bean is not the proper name for a class.

```
Country_Bean
```

Will be:

```
CountryBean
```

The scope variable name country_Bean is also wrong.

```
country_Bean
```

Will be:

```
countryBean
```

Also if using Eclipse, try to use the auto format as it will make the code much prettier (CTRL + SHIFT + F).

Comment: I have used it but not with listview so I am using single radiobutton and using RadioGroup may not be good is where only single radiobutton is needed. Yes it may be the easy way but more items will be in my listview, more radiogroups will be created. Using radioGroup will be my Last resort to complete this. Thank you.

Comment: Sure sir I will mind it next time. I appreciate your suggestions. Thank you.